# Suggest some good resources for implementing Facebook Signup and Login with CodeIgniter?

Tags: codeigniter, facebook

Most of what I've found via a google search are either buggy or refer to a deprecated version of the API/SDK....can anyone share a link to resources that deal with the most recent version of the facebook php sdk

Answer (score 0):

I'm pretty sure this uses the latest Facebook API

http://www.haughin.com/code/